# Can I use variables in place of key names in my query?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'd like to do this:

```
customers.findOneAndUpdate({'name':data.tenant,data.contentType+'.name':data.name},{data.contentType+'.$.archived':true},function(err,data2){
```

But this is giving me compilation errors at the dot of `data.contentType`.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

If I were to do `'files.name'` as a single string, it'd work, but `data.contentType+'.name'` won't compile.

Comment: I'm guessing the comma and the invalid structure of the objects has something to do with it ?

Comment: And no, you can't use variables as keys directly, you'll need bracket notation for that.

Comment: @adeneo What's invalid about it? and how do I use bracket notation for what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use bracket notation for that

```
var obj  = {name : data.tenant},
    obj2 = {};

obj[data.contentType+'.name'] = data.name;
obj2[data.contentType+'.$.archived'] = true;

customers.findOneAndUpdate(obj, obj2, function(err,data2){ ...
```